# I want my code to print the largest and smallest number in an array. Why isn't this working?

Tags: java

```
public class Numbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int w[] = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 3 };
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        if (w[i] > w[i]++) {
            w[i] = max;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < w.length; j++) {
            if (w[j] < w[j]++) {
                w[j] = min;
            }

            System.out.println(min + max);
           }

       }
   }
}
```

All I get for output is this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why does it even print the 0 that many times?

Comment: This only requires 1 loop (or two, non-nested). Do you understand what you've written?

Comment: try max= w[i] instead of the other way aorund :) and yeah, can be done in one loop

Comment: Also, it is printing 0 multiple times because println is inside your nested loop. Put it outside.

Comment: `w[i] > w[i]++` is always false: you are checking if something is greater than itself, and then incrementing that something. As such, never mind that you are never setting min or max in the conditionals' bodies, you never execute the conditionals' bodies at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never mutate min or max. within your loops you change the array. when you set w[i] = max, you are setting the item at place i to = 0(which is what you initialized min and max at.)

change the order to

```
max=w[i]
```

or

```
min=w[i]
```

as for WHY its printing that many times, you have the print statement in your for loop, move the print statement outside of the for loop

I would also change the print statement to be

```
System.out.println("Max= " + max + "Min= " + min)
```

Just makes the results a little clearer